# Registering dependency on 'wp-posts-to-posts' from a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-posts-to-posts

I have custom plugin which registers multiple CPT's and i want to reuse the features of [wp-posts-to-posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to define relationships. I'm just wondering what is the correct/best way to include the api.php file within my own plugin?

```
function my_connection_types() {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/posts-to-posts/core/api.php' );
    // Make sure the Posts 2 Posts plugin is active.
    if ( !function_exists( 'p2p_register_connection_type' ) )
        return;

    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
            'name' => 'events_to_races',
            'from' => 'event',
            'to' => 'race',
            'cardinality' => 'one-to-many'
    ) );
}
```

Comment: If the posts-to-posts plugin is running on your site, I am not sure you'd need to include `api.php` but of course that depends on how the plugin works making the question off-topic as dependent on third party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to load the plugin yourself, check for its existence on your activation hook.

If it's not activated, throw an error; WordPress will display the message & prevent activation of your plugin.